# different dropdown buttons open the same menu in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible?
I tried the following code and it works. However, when the buttons are placed at different div's on the page, the menu is positioned at the wrong places.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu">Hello1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu">Hello1</button>

<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="menu">
    <li>Hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mE62z/

Comment: That is my goal. I'm asking if it's possible to do it correctly. Now, it's not working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Bootstrap accommodates this. Cloning might work:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mE62z/5

```
$('#menu').clone().attr('id','menu2').appendTo('body');
$('#menu2').addClass('pull-right');
```